# How can i connect a tunnel mesh with video 2D imported and then render it?

Tags: rendering, mesh, import, video, compositing-nodes

I created a tunnel using: a cylinder, an array, a bezier and a noise texture to model the shape of the tunnel.
Now I want to link the start of the tunnel with a video clip uploaded via empty.

Could you give me some useful advice to connect the mesh to the 2D video?
I also did a render test but the imported video is not calculated during the render. Did i import wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: i am still not sure what effect you want to achieve...do you want something like this? https://youtu.be/g8qbarXVNcQ

Comment: well, not really. more or less yes. but all in a realistic version, and instead of suzanne my video clip recorded with the real camera. and try to make it look realistic here.

Comment: So what's been the final outcome here?  Have you got this going or not?  If I'm guessing right, you've got a camera inside a 3D mesh cave that's moving towards the cave entrance.  If that's the case Blender is ideally suited for this so long as you're not bent on using nodes.  See the clip - walking out of a mesh turbo lift, to continue seamlessly into and along a previously taken video - 

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtkhCKZLZs_PhAAc5ybfDetiKh8z?e=xCqECJ

Answer (score 0):

You can use this material setup to render a video:

[image]

Comment: yes but where did you put this material?

Comment: I have to import it as image as planes, but in view render it appears completely dark, almost black.

Comment: As I said - provide your blend file - then we can help you. You didn’t provide any useful information…